Can a smooth function be extended from half-space to whole space?
EDIT: It is answered by Michael: It's the Whitney extension theorem or Borel's lemma.
I'll use: $\;E=\mathbb{R}^n$, $\;x\in E$, $\;|x|=1\;$ and $\;H=\{y\in E\,|\,\langle x,y\rangle\geq0\}$.
In classical sense,
we say that a function $f:H\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is smooth if it can be extended to a smooth function on some neighborhood of $H$ in $E$. This is valid for any definition of "smoothness": $C^1$, $C^k$, $C^\infty$ or even $C^\omega$.
In direct sense,
a function $f:X\rightarrow\mathbb{R}\;$ (for any open $X\subseteq\mathbb{R}^n$) is differentiable if it can be approximated by a linear function at any point (I assume the details are already clear to the reader*). We can then take coordinate coefficients of these linear functionals and get what we call partial derivatives. We then recursively require these partial derivatives to be differentiable themselves and so on, ultimately we get the definition of a $C^\infty$ smooth function.
But direct sense also works even if $X$ is not open. For example, if $X$ is closed.

If a function $f:H\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is $C^\infty$ smooth in direct sense, is it $C^\infty$ smooth in classical sense too?

I have already answered it affirmatively in case $n=1$ (I at least think so), but I have no idea how to answer the $n=2$ case.
$$ $$
In case the details of linear approximations aren't clear:
A function $f:X\rightarrow\mathbb{R},\;X\subseteq\mathbb{R}^n$ is differentiable at $x\in X$ iff there exists a linear function $L:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ and a "small" function $\mu:[0,\infty)\rightarrow[0,\infty)$ (that is $\lim_{t\rightarrow0}\mu(t)=0$) such that:
$$\forall y\in X\;:\;|f(y)-f(x)-L(y-x)|\leq|x-y|\cdot\mu(|x-y|).$$

Usually a function is considered "smooth" if it is differentiable and its derivative is continuous. So infinitely differentiable is not required.

I find the definition of "direct sense" to be indirect. I do not know what it means. Something about and so on and so on. I understand the classical sense.

@Michael I have edited the question to be more precise, thank you for pointing at this unclear detail.

@Michael Direct sense means partial derivates have partial derivates, and these 2nd partial derivates have their own partial derivatives and so on... Is it clear now or should I define it really rigorously?

Existence of partial derivatives does not imply differentiable. Also, even if differentiable, it seems your "direct sense" is requiring many layered derivatives to exist, while "classical sense" does not.

@Michael Okay, let's clear it out step by step. I firstly require the function to be differentiable and then I define partial derivates. It is not the other way around. So I hope that point is resolved. Secondly, I would like you to tell me your assumed definition of a $C^\infty$ smooth function (the one I hope to call classical).

You originally said that I could use any (my) definition of smooth, which is the only one I would like to define (defined in my first comment). Your title suggests you want to consider extensions of a given function. The McShane-Whitney theorem may help. One statement (not necessarily the one I like the best) is here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitney_extension_theorem

@Michael Yes! I am happy we understood each other at the end. And you have answered my question! Thank you.

@Michael I disagree with your definition, I have seen issues when people ask in MSE about smooth like just differentiable or smooth like class $C^\infty$, which is specially important since there exist analytic functions which are always class $C^\infty$, but there exist also class $C^\infty$ function that are not analytic. See Non-Analytic smooth functions, Smooth Bump functions, Fabius function

you should consider a sequence $[f(0), f'(0), f''(0), f'''(0),...]$, and then the values of $f$ in range $[0..n]$ can be recovered using $f^{(n+1)}(k) = f^{(n)}(k+1)-f^{(n)}(k)$, when $\Delta x=1$ while $\Delta x \rightarrow 0$ in $\lim_{\Delta x\rightarrow 0}\frac{f(x+\Delta x)-f(x)}{\Delta x}$.
To recover the negative side, the process just need to be flipped from $[0..n]$ to $[-n..0]$, with 0 still in the sequence.
Note that this process has significant problems with current computer architectures, given that the numbers in pascal's triangle grow too large somewhere around line 21 in pascal's triangle. Proper bigints are needed to do the calculations. So if you want to avoid bigints, there's n<21 as limit what you can do.
Also the process has interpolation issues, as it uses polynomial interpolation (of degree $\leq n$) in between f(k) and f(k+1), so certain complicated functions outside of polynomials are out of reach for this technique. But polynomial interpolation is exactly what is needed for extending from half-space to full space.
Full details can be found from Taylor's theorem in wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor%27s_theorem
especially important are the following aspects:
$f(x+k) = e^{k\cdot \frac{d}{dx}} f(x)$
Using translation operator which gives you the polynomial interpolation. To actually calculate this, use $e^{x}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^n}{n!}$, so that $f(x+k) = e^{k\cdot \frac{d}{dx}} f(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{{k^n \cdot \frac{d^n}{dx^n}}}{n!} f(x)$, which gives you standard taylor's theorem treatment.

I am sorry, this webiste is for strict mathematics. Your answer, even though sound practiaclly, does not really fit as an answer to my question.

I suggest you clear out the difference between the next terms: $C^\infty$ smoothness and real analytic, ie $C^\omega$ smoothness. Not all smooth functions have a converging Taylor's series.

See Non-Analytic smooth functions, Smooth Bump functions, Fabius function

well, I have no better way to get derivatives in the full space to match the derivatives of the half space. Transfering enough information from the right side to the left side just requires infinite operations which are beyond our current computer hardware capabilities,

for example, the information transfer problem prevents "simple" solutions like $f(-x)=f(x)$, which look plausible until you start the information transfer process and find out sampling the $x\in R$ is required for the information transfer.

@tp1 But there are no computers in mathematics... I really don't understand how you could confuse math with engineering so badly...

@cnikbesku: it distrupts your worldview that real world has limitations like inability to iterate past infinite?
